# How to save Images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am working on a wpf application. I am having one image, i have put some more images on it, with lowered transparency(sort of watermarking you can say). Is their any way to save the present look of the two or three images(watermarked images) into one new image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RenderTargetBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to render Visuals, to render your stack of images you should place them in some wrapping control (if only temporarily). [This article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/150676.aspx) might be helpful.